# Imprimir codigos de barra ESC/POS (vertical)

Tags: epson

quiero imprimir códigos de barra en impresoras térmicas de forma vertical usando comandos ESC/POS, hoy puedo imprimirlos de forma horizontal usando los siguiente comandos.

new Indice = 1
// ===========PRINT BAR CODE ============= //
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0x1D) //GS
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,'f') //f
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,3) //Select fon

```
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0x1D) //GS
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,'H') //H
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0) //Select print position

xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0x1D) //GS
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,'w') //w
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,SizeCodeBar) //Set width size to 3t

xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0x1D) //GS
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,'h') //h
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,180) //Set height

xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0x1D) //GS
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,'k') //k
xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,2) //Print bar code  

for (Indice = 2; Indice < 14; Indice++) 
{
    xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,Num[Indice])
}

xSerialSendByte (SERIAL_CH,0)//Terminador
```